# how to get GSM7 bit encode and decode in php?

Tags: php, decode, encode

I am working on Greek language integration. I have message in greek language and my issue is to pass this message into url with GSM7 encode.
I try to find GSM7 bit encode and decode in PHP, but I could not find it.

I want to encode "EXETE ΔIAΓPAΦEI EΠITYXΩΣ AΠO TIΣ ΛIΣTEΣ MAΣ" to GSM7 bit encode.

Please help if anyone know..